# Website Facebook Like button disappears after clicking

Tags: html, facebook-like

There was a Facebook button 9 years ago that accumulated 6 clicks but the code for this button was deleted. I need to put the button back.

The new Like button correctly showed 6 clicks and when its clicked there is a 1/2 second pause, then it disappears. It comes back when the page is reloaded. The button is now up to 7 clicks so I think its working, just disappearing after clicking. (Edge and Firefox it disappears.)

The Facebook debug tool gives: Warning - The following required properties are missing: fb:app_id. AND Response code - 206.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Home</title>

<meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.our-site.com" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="Home" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="our description." />
<meta property="og:image"         content="https://www.our-site.com/images/logo002.jpg" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_AU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v18.0" nonce="xjkEXir5"></script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.our-site.com" data-width="" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-share="false"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using Firefox and right clicking in the empty space left by the Like button and selecting Inspect -> Console shows an error message: “X-Frame-Options“ directive set to “DENY“. This directive is set on the server and I have no access to it. If I had access I would set the directive to "SAMEORIGIN" and do a test

Answer (score 0):

The like button disappears because Facebook has not yet synced the user's cookies, for some reason Firefox is notorious. It will disappear when it notices the user is not logged into Facebook.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this? If the problem is notorious, there should be plenty out there.